# Back-propagating gradients through a sparse tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, backpropagation

I have a normal feed-forward network that produces a vector v. The elements of v are then used as the non-zero entries of a sparse matrix M (assume the coordinates are predefined). The sparse matrix is then multiplied by a dense vector and a loss is defined on the resulting scalar. I want to back-propagate the loss w.r.t. the weights of the network, which entails going through the sparse matrix.

This seems like a perfectly reasonable use-case for a sparse matrix, but it appears that such functionality is not supported. Indeed, even calling tf.gradients(M,[v]) produces an error:

> AttributeError: 'SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'value_index'

Am I doing something wrong or am I correct in presuming that this functionality doesn't (yet?) exist? If the latter, then is there a work-around for this particular use-case short of rewriting all of the sparse tensor operations with gradients defined?

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on this does work, taking the gradient of the `values` of a `SparseTensor` directly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sparse_values = tf.identity(tf.Variable(tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])))
sparse_indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], dtype=tf.int64)
sparse_matrix = tf.SparseTensor(sparse_indices, sparse_values, [3, 3])
multiplied = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(sparse_matrix, tf.eye(3))
loss = tf.reduce_sum(multiplied)
gradients = tf.gradients(loss, [sparse_values])
with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(session.run(gradients))
```

Prints (on TensorFlow 0.12.1):

```
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.], dtype=float32)]
```

Why the `tf.identity` op is necessary for the gradient to be defined I haven't quite figured out (probably something to do with ref dtypes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fishing around in the dark here, working from code and documentation, not experience.

The `Tensor` class creator is:

```
def __init__(self, op, value_index, dtype):
    #  value_index: An `int`. Index of the operation's endpoint that produces this tensor.
```

The `value_index` is used to generate the `Tensor` name.

The `SparseTensor` one is

```
def __init__(self, indices, values, dense_shape):
```

Nowhere in it's definition file `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py` is `value_index` referenced.

Its arguments are Tensors, presumably each with its own `value_index`.

Else where it appears that a `SparseTensor` is an alternative to a `IndexedSlices`, which also contains tensors.

The inputs to `tf.gradients` are all

```
A `Tensor` or list of tensors
```

The `gradients` definition file has a `_IndexedSlicesToTensor` method, but nothing equivalent for `SparseTensor`.  So there seems to be some sort of automatic conversion to dense in the case of `IndexedSlices` (with a warning if the result is too big), but not for `SparseTensors`.  I don't know if that'a case of incomplete development, or an incompatibility that makes it impossible.